# How do I limit an objects movement in xcode for iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode

this is my first ever question so apologies if it's not descriptive enough.

I currently have an object that can be moved along an x axis with dragging. I need to limit it's movement to half of the screen.

Can anyone help

Comment: Is the object a UIView? How are you moving it? Can you show your dragging code?

Comment: the object is a UIImageView, I'm moving it with a simple UITouch here's what I have :
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view]
CGPoint yLocation = CGPointMake(object.center.x,location.y)
object.center = yLocation;
so the object can be dragged from one side of the screen to the other....I just need it to limit it's movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that is simple. Assuming we are talking about moving a `UIView`:

```
// Only move the object if its right bounding box position is
// in the first half of the screen

if ((someObjectView.frame.origin.x + someObjectView.frame.size.width) < 
        (containingView.bounds.size.width / 2.0) {
    // Move the object
}
```

You fill in the blanks :-)

Comment: thanks St3fan, it's a UIImageView. is it called a bounding box ? I think that's where I may have gone wrong !!

Comment: The correct term in iPhone land is `frame`: the `frame` is the position of a view, expressed in coordinates in its superview.